# Not printing to file java

Tags: java, file-writing

I am trying to log what my program is doing. Currently I'm using PrintWriter but all it produces is a blank txt file. Can someone please correct my code if possible or give any suggestions.

```
    public class Log {
public static void log(String string){
    if(string != null) {
        System.out.println("log ".concat(string));
        try {
            PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt"));
            out.println("log ".concat(string));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void log(String[] strings) {
    if (strings == null) return;
    for(String string : strings) {
        if (string != null) {
            System.out.println("log ".concat(string));
            try {
                PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt"));
                out.println("log ".concat(string));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to flush the PrintWriter to get data written in the file

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt"));
out.println("log ".concat(string));
out.flush();
```

If you're done with writing into file you should close the PrintWriter which will also cause data to be written

```
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must close the file. Like this:

```
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt"));
out.println("log ".concat(string));
out.close();
```

As an aside, you can make your second method much cleaner:

```
public static void log(String[] strings) {
    if (strings == null) return;
    for(String string : strings) {
        log(string);
    }
}
```

Any time you are copy pasting the same code, you should be looking for a way to use encapsulation / method calls to remove duplicated code. That will make it easier to change things later if you need to.